# Play 3gp Video File on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, 3gp

I've found quite a few posts saying, "The documentation says that iOS can play 3GP files, here's a link to Apple's docs", but the reality of the situation is: No Apple sample code plays a 3GP video file.

Can anyone point me to any sample of iOS code that can play a 3GP file? Or is there a definitive answer that says that MPMoviePlayerViewController just can't do it?

I emailed the test video to my iPad, and I can play the 3gp video attachment from the Mail app, so I'm pretty sure the iPad has the correct video Codec.

Help is definitely appreciated.

Peter

Comment: Searches are a bit cryptic for me as well. iPhone 1 does *not* play 3GP according to iphone support forum; I am fairly sure devices begin to somewhere... but where?